# how to compute 'nearby' nodes with networkx

Tags: python, math, networkx

What I'm looking for here may well be a built-in function in `networkx`, and have a mathematical name - if so, I'd like to know what it is! it is very difficult to Google for, it seems.

Given a graph `G` and a starting node `i`, I'd like to find the subgraph of all the nodes "within `P` edges" from `i` - that is, those that are connected to `i` by a path of less than `P` edges.

My draft implementation for this is:

```py
import networkx as nx

N = 30
G = nx.Graph()

# populate the graph...
G.add_cycle(range(N))

# the starting node:
i = 15

# the 'distance' limit:
P = 4

neighborhood = [i]
new_neighbors = [i]
depth = 0

while depth < P:
    new_neighbors = list(set(sum([
        [k for k in G[j].keys() if k not in neighborhood]
    for j in new_neighbors], [])))

    neighborhood.extend(new_neighbors)

    depth += 1

Gneighbors = G.subgraph(neighborhood)
```

This code works, by the way, so I don't need help with the implementation. I would simply like to know if this has a name, and whether it is provided by the `networkx` library.

It is very useful when your code is crashing and you want to see why - you can render just the "locality/region" of the graph near the problem node.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`single_source_shortest_path`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.unweighted.single_source_shortest_path.html?highlight=single_source_shortest_path#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.unweighted.single_source_shortest_path) or [`single_source_shortest_path_length`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.unweighted.single_source_shortest_path_length.html?highlight=single_source_shortest_path#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.unweighted.single_source_shortest_path_length) with a cutoff of `p`

Something like:

```
nx.single_source_shortest_path_length(G ,source=i, cutoff=p)
```

Comment: Thanks, in fact it looks like nx.single_source_shortest_path_length would be better, since that returns less data (I assume it also does less work). But yes, this is the least code to write/maintain, thanks!

Answer (score 25):

Two years late, but I was looking for this same thing and found a built-in that I think will get the subgraph you want: [`ego_graph`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.ego.ego_graph.html?highlight=ego_graph#networkx.generators.ego.ego_graph). The function signature and documentation:

```
ego_graph(G, n, radius=1, center=True, undirected=False, distance=None)
```

> Returns induced subgraph of neighbors centered at node n within a given radius.

Comment: Really really useful stuff! +1